# Linux jobs command - how to see the full path of the running process

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh, suse

I am using Linux SUSE 11 and running a lot of jobs. 
The path of each job is very long , for example:

```
cmd>/user/data/some/very/very/very/long/path/to/my/command/run_me param0 param1 param2
```

When I am running a lot of these commands I want to know which is finished and which is running. Let say after a day or so. 
Using 'jobs' command I see only the following :

```
[1]  + Running                        ...
[2]  + Running                        ...
[3]  + Running                        ...
[4]  + Running                        ...
```

So I can't know which exact command is running.

Using `top` command is not helpful either, because is is showing the process and not the exact script/program I am running.

My shell is `/usr/bin/tcsh`

Comment: You should change your shell to [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/)

Comment: And you should have shorter executable paths. For example, make a symlink from `~/bin/run_me` (or `/usr/local/bin/run_me` or `/opt/bin/run_me` ...) to `/user/data/some/very/very/very/long/path/to/my/command/run_me`

Comment: Or Bash or a number of others.  I managed to suppress the urge to suggest this to the poster, but now the cat's out of the bag.  [`t?csh` should be avoided](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) but I suppose everybody already knows.

Answer (score 1):

In `tcsh`, `jobs -l` gives you a "long" listing which includes the PID.  You can then use this number to examine the jobs with `ps` or groping around in the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem or whatever.

```
% jobs -l
[1]  + 19038 Running                       tail --follow=name /path/to/long/and/complex /long/and/complex/files /and/so/on ...
```

From this listing, you can grab `19038` and see what it's really doing.

```
% ps -o args= --width 1200 19945
tail --follow=name /path/to/long/and/complex /long/and/complex/files /and/so/on /really/long /etc/motd
```

as well as

```
% tr '\0' '\n' </proc/19038/cmdline 
tail
--follow=name
/path/to/long/and/complex
/long/and/complex/files
/and/so/on
/really/long
/etc/motd
```

or, somewhat messily, with `top`:

```
% setenv COLUMNS 512

% top -b -n1 -c -p 19038
```

(The output is too ugly to show here and does not add anything useful.)

Comment: jobs -l gives same result but with pid numbers, for example:
    [2]  -  8989 Running                        ...    ps giving only the processes and not the command which was executed.

Comment: But you can use this number to examine e.g. `/proc/8989/cmd` to obtain precisely the information you need.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how can I examine the /proc/ID/cwd folder? What can I check there? How can I determine the param0 to param2 from my example above?

Comment: Sorry, typo (or rather, faulty memory); that's `/proc/8989/cmdline` where 8989 is the PID you want to examine.  This shows the full command line, zero-terminated.  Updated answer with details.  Hope this helps.